# smooth homotopy 4-balls with sphere boundary in dimension 4

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

What follows is, as far as I can tell, totally standard folklore.  I have one particular point of confusion, other than that, I wanted to confirm that I am uttering the incantations correctly.

The smooth 4-dimensional Poincare conjecture (SPC4) is the statement that any smooth 4-dimensional manifold $\Sigma$ that is homeomorphic to $S^4$ is diffeomorphic to $S^4$.  Is SPC4 equivalent to the conjecture that any smooth 4-manifold $B$ with $\partial B = S^3$ that is homotopy equivalent to $B^4$ is diffeomorphic to $B^4$?

**Going one direction:** Assume SPC4 is true.

If $B$ is a homotopy 4-sphere with $\partial B = S^3$ then we can fill the boundary with $B^4$ and we obtain a simply connected (by van Kampen) homology $S^4$ (by Mayer-Vietoris), which (by Hurewicz and Whitehead) must be a homotopy $S^4$, which (by Freedman) must be homeomorphic to $S^4$, which (assuming SPC4) is then diffeomorphic to $S^4$.

I imagine that we are about ready to conclude that $B$ must be standard - since it is now sitting inside of $S^4$ with its boundary bounding a standard $B^4$ on the other side.  How do we finish up? Can we ambiently isotope $S^4$ so as to have the image of the $S^3$ be just the usual $S^3 \subset S^4$?

**Going the other direction:** Assume that every smooth homotopy $B^4$ with boundary $S^3$ is diffeomorphic to $B^4$.

Suppose that $\Sigma$ is a smooth homotopy $S^4$.  Take a small 4-ball $B^4$ in $\Sigma$ and remove it.  What is left (by van Kampen) is a smooth homotopy $B^4$ with boundary $S^3$ which (by assumption) is then diffeomorphic to $B^4$.  Now (by Cerf) since $\Sigma$ is just the union of two copies of $B^4$, it is in fact diffeomorphic to $S^4$.

Comment: You might find this post https://lamington.wordpress.com/2013/10/18/scharlemann-on-schoenflies/ and Ian Agol's first comment helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can perform that ambient isotopy: any oriented embedding $i: B^n \to M^n$ is isotopic to any other. (This is a lemma proven independently by Cerf and Palais<sup>1</sup>, but the idea is quite clear: shrink the image of $i$ until it's contained in the chart, then take the limit that defines the derivative of a map.)

In particular, if $h$ is your diffeomorphism $B \cup_{\partial B} B^4 \to S^4$, you may isotope the embedding of $h(B^4)$ so that it is the standard inclusion of the north hemisphere. Then $h$ restricts to a diffeomorphism $h: B \to B^4$, where this $B^4$ is the southern hemisphere of $S^4$.

<sup>1</sup>The references given on [this Manifold Atlas page](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Connected_sum) are [Palais, Theorem 5.5](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1959-092-01/S0002-9947-1959-0116352-7/home.html) (the essential content is Lemma 5.2) and somewhere in [Cerf's treatise](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=BSMF_1961__89__227_0) on embedding spaces.

Comment: Are you sure the fact about balls is is due Smale? This is usually called the Palais (196)-Cerf (1961) lemma.

Comment: @DannyRuberman No, but I'm unsure what I was thinking of! I will edit the reference.

Comment: The specific reference in the Cerf paper is section 5.1.4.  (It's easier to find if you search for "boule" rather than "disque" (or "bisque" as auto-correct would have it).) I think of the Palais result as being from Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 11 1960 274–277, but you are right about the earlier one.

Comment: @DannyRuberman Thanks for your care in making sure the references were right.